# kendo editor textbox with popup window

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I'm using kendo editor textbox in one popup window when I'm firing the button that will shown in that I can apply my text as well as apply the typed text to another text area but I'm getting html encoded text.

1) I need clear edited text.

2) When I'm in popup window I need to find the parant text area what text I'm getting from that text need to replace. But here I'm replacing all the textarea inside the div I have.

this code im using

HTML:

```
 <td colspan="2">
<textarea style="width: 170px;height: 60px;" data-bind="value:invHText"></textarea>
<button type="button" data-bind="click: onClick" class="editButton">Edit</button>
  </td>
```

For popup window:

```
<div id="orderWindow" style="display: none;">
    <span id="currentText" style="display:none;"></span>
    <div id='orderPage'>
        <textarea id="editor" rows="10" cols="30" style="height: 360px">
                </textarea>
    </div>
    <div class='formButtons' style="float: right;margin-top: 5px;">
        <button id='button_apply' class="k-button">Apply</button>
         <button id='button_close' class="k-button">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
self.onClick = function (context, e) {
            var tarel = $(e.target)[0];
            var el = $(tarel).parent().find('textarea').val();

            $('#orderPage').empty();
            $('#orderPage').html('<textarea id="editor" rows="10" cols="30" style="height: 360px"></textarea>');
            $("#editor").kendoEditor({
                value: el,
                encoded: false   
                    });

           $('#orderWindow').kendoWindow({
                title: "Rich TextBox",
                resizable: true,
                modal: true,
                width: 550,
                draggable: true,

            }).data("kendoWindow").center().open();

           $("#button_apply").click(function () {
               var editor = $("#editor").data('kendoEditor');

               var id = $("table td textarea").parent();

               alert(id);
               $('textarea').val(editor.value());
               var orderWindow = $('#orderWindow').data("kendoWindow");
               orderWindow.close();
           });
           $("#button_close").click(function () {
               var orderWindow = $('#orderWindow').data("kendoWindow");
               orderWindow.close();
            });
        };
```

Comment: and what's the question?

Comment: From that im getting text with html tags but i need only text? and i need to apply this to multiple buttons for the multiple text box in same page.